# Macro to Clear multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my code that automatically runs the TimeStamp Macro when I open the workbook. However, it only runs if the Time is 6:45 am or later. My problem is that I am trying to get it to clear the cell contents in Columns A through D from Row 2 and on if the time is before 6:45 am and before it runs the TimeStamp macro. I tried to do it with just Column A and the debugger says that the top line is an issue. I can't seem to figure out why it is an issue though. I assume I am breaking some sort of syntax rule but I am not sure.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Time > TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) Then
    Call TimeStamp
    Else
        Sub Clear()
            Dim wb3 As Workbook
            Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
                With wb3.Worksheets("Avnet")
                 .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
                End With
        End Sub
    Application.Wait "06:45:00"
    Call TimeStamp
End Sub
```

It worked prior to me adding in the Sub Clear() section...

UPDATE:
Just tried making the Sub Clear() a separate module and using the `call Clear()` but that didnt work either. Here is what it looked like

The Clear () Code

```
Sub Clear()
    Dim wb3 As Workbook
    Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
    With wb3.Worksheets("Avnet")
        Range("A2:A" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

The Part to call the Clear()

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Time > TimeSerial(20, 0, 0) Then
    Call TimeStamp
    Else
    Call Clear
    Application.Wait "19:35:00"
    Call TimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: Please be more specific; phrases such as "doesn't seem to like it." and "didn't work" are not helpful. Is the problem that the code won't run at all, or it runs but doesn't do what you want? If the former, please step thru your code with the debugger and tell us what line is failing. If the latter, we will need to know the current behaviour and the desired behaviour.

Comment: You're missing an `'End If` in `Workbook_Open` (see code in my answer below). This might fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a sub within a sub will not work (I'm 99.9999% sure, but it's never entered my head to try this!)

Move your `Sub Clear` declaration so that it's after `Workbook_Open`, and then just call `Clear` from within `Workbook_Open`, in the same way that you call `TimeStamp`. (You're also missing an `End If'` at the end of WorkBook_open)

So your code would become:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Time > TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) Then
        Call TimeStamp
    Else
        Call Clear 
        Application.Wait "06:45:00"
        Call TimeStamp
    End If 
End Sub

Sub Clear()
    Dim wb3 As Workbook
    Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
    With wb3.Worksheets("Avnet")
       .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

As an aside, your Workbook_Open code can be simplified to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Time <= TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) Then
        Call Clear 
        Application.Wait "06:45:00"
    End If 

    Call TimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: You know you have been working for too long when you forget to end your If/Then... But I didn't know you couldn't declare a sub within another sub, just went ahead and did it but its good to know I can't. Thanks!!

Comment: I've got another problem not related to this that I just really don't know how to research unlike anything else. If I post a new question, think you could give it a look?

Comment: Post away. I probably won't be able to look at it immediately, but someone else may be able to.